# Open Terminal from shell and execute commands

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, applescript

I am lazy so I want to write a shell script to open my dev environment. I setup two commands `dev` and `dev-startup`. When I run `dev /directory/path` it should open a new terminal window at `/directory/path` and execute `dev-startup`.

I'm not sure how to open the terminal window at a specific directory and then run a final command to run the tools I need to setup the environment.

I'm running OSX, so maybe AppleScript is the answer?

Comment: Hey, that's not lazy, that's efficiency!

Answer (score 16):

Option 1 with xterm (will automatically close the window when completed):

```
xterm -e "cd /tmp/; watch 'pwd;date'"
```

Option 2 with MacOS terminal:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd /tmp;pwd"'
```

Comment: With the second command I've found a weird interaction. Whenever I open a new tab it executes the command.

Comment: I am sure you can adjust the osascript so it will only do it once.

Comment: Is this also possible on iTerm? This command didn't work: `osascript -e 'tell application "iTerm" to do script "cd /tmp;pwd"'`

Comment: Yes, see https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-scripting.html