# Schedule cron job to open Terminal and run command sequentially

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, cron, scheduled-tasks

I scheduled a cron job on a Mac to open Terminal every day at 11PM as follows:

```
0 23 * * * open -a Terminal
```

That works great! But what I would like is to not only open Terminal, but also to run a simple command within it. From looking online, [it looks as if cron commands can be chained with `&&`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto):

```
0 23 * * * open -a Terminal && echo 'Hello, world!'
```

However, this modified cron job only opens Terminal without running the second command there. **Any thoughts on how I can get the cron job to do both?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great answers already provided by [pah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5595825/pah) and [Sameer Naik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734744/sameer-naik), but I ended up going with an even simpler solution using AppleScripts, inspired by [an SO answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31526199/2932774).

```
0 23 * * * osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "echo \"Hello, world\"!"'
```

Comment: Very interesting solution :)

Comment: Just my personal observation on SO so far. Many people think termimal to be an application that lets you execute some obscure commands. But it merely exposes you to UNIX shell command prompt. There are other terminal softwares like iTerm2 that do the same function. So IMHO, using a shell script invoked via cron is simplest, but I understand that "simpler" depends on everyone's comfort level.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by obscure commands, Terminal is pretty straightforward. One line of code seems preferable to a new file. Not really about comfort level, more about practicality.

Comment: This is much cleaner than continually editing the bash_profile, nice idea.

Answer (score 3):

The following answer [after the separator] assumes that you want to run the second command **within** [inside] the Terminal. Otherwise you just need to swap the commands on your cronjob (because currently, as you have it, the `echo` will only execute **after** `Terminal` exits), such as:

```
0 23 * * * echo 'Hello, world!' && open -a Terminal
```

---

Now, assuming you want to run the command **within** the newly spawned terminal:

I'm not aware that `Terminal` application (from `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal`) accepts [i.e., interprets] any command line arguments nor will it read anything from [a standard output redirected to] standard input.

What you're doing with `open -a Terminal && echo 'Hello, world!'` is basically calling the `Terminal` application *and* [if successful] print `'Hello, world!'` on the same shell that called the previous command (the `Terminal`). This is analogous to executing two separate commands in the same shell, but only executing the latest if the first succeeds.

If you want a specific command (say `echo 'Hello, world!'`) to be executed every time `bash` (currently the default osx shell) is loaded for the current user (as in, every time the user opens a `Terminal`), you can add that command to `~/.bash_profile`. For instance:

```
echo "echo 'Hello, world!'" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Now when you open a `Terminal`, the command `echo 'Hello, world!'" will be executed.

Since the latest version of MacOSX does not include a `~/.bash_profile` by default for any user, you can take advantage of this and change your crontab to:

```
0 23 * * * echo "echo 'Hello, world!' > ~/.bash_profile" && open -a Terminal
```

This basically will replace the contents of `~/.bash_profile` for every time this crontab entry is executed and opens the `Terminal`.

The downside of doing that this way is that whatever you put inside `~/.bash_profile`, will be executed for every opened `Terminal`, regardless of being the one from the crontab, or any other the user may open at any given time.

To solve this, you can also remove the `~/.bash_profile` file from within it, by placing a trailing `rm -f ~/.bash_profile` command after the `echo 'Hello, world!'`:

```
0 23 * * * echo "echo 'Hello, world!'; rm -f ~/.bash_profile" > ~/.bash_profile" && open -a Terminal
```

This will cause that when `Terminal` opens and calls `bash`, all the `~/.bash_profile` commands will be executed, including the trailing `rm -f ~/.bash_profile`, so the next call to `Terminal` won't trigger your command again since the `~/.bash_profile` no longer exists.

**Sidenote:** If, for some reason, you already have a `~/.bash_profile` file, instead of replacing the whole contents of it and removing it after, you can backup the original, append your commands [including the one to restore the original file] and open the terminal. But I think this is not your case (anyway, if it is, I can extend this answer with the details).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script say my_cron_job.sh and execute it via cron
`0 23 * * * my_cron_job.sh`
Specify absolute path to the script e.g. /users/your_user_name/scripts/my_cron_job.sh